# Polymer 2 - Cannot read property 'instanceCount' of undefined

Tags: polymer

`window.Polymer = {rootPath: '/'};` caused Cannot read property 'instanceCount' of undefined.
What did I miss?

Comment: You have a problem with paths to your local files. They can't be found. So changing path to your files should fix it

Answer (score 0):

With the line `window.Polymer = {rootPath: '/'};` you overwrite your local polymer instance. Better write `window.Polymer.rootPath = '/';`